# Binding resource data to custom winjs control

Tags: winapi, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs

I am trying to create a custom placeholder control. Here is the code excerpt:

```
(function () {
    var Placeholder = WinJS.Class.define(function ctor(elem, options) {
        this.element = elem || document.createElement('div');
        this.element.winControl = this;

        WinJS.UI.setOptions(this, options);

        this.init();
    },
    {
        element: {
            get: function () {
                return this._element;
            },
            set: function (value) {
                this._element = value;
            }
        },

        placeholder: {
            get: function () {
                return this._placeholder;
            },
            set: function (value) {
                this._placeholder = value;

                this._placeholderElement.textContent = value;
            }
        },

        placeholderClass: {
            get: function () {
                return this._placeholderClass;
            },
            set: function (value) {
                this._placeholderClass = value;

                this._placeholderElement.classList.add(value);
            }
        },

        _placeholderElement: null,

        init: function () {
            this._addPlaceholder();
        },

        _addPlaceholder: function () {
            /* Code to add placeholder. */
        }
    });

    WinJS.Namespace.define("ControlX", { Placeholder: Placeholder });
})();
```

I am trying to use this control in the html in this manner :

```
<div data-win-control="ControlX.Placeholder" data-win-res="{winControl:{placeholder:'resHeight'}}"><input type="text"/></div>
```

When I set the placeholder value using the `data-win-res` attribute, I am getting an exception:

> "Unable to set property 'placeholder' of undefined or null reference"

According to this article:
[How to localize WinJS controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj673579.aspx) we can bind resource strings to winControl attributes too.

What am I doing wrong?

Is there any other way to bind resource string to a winControl property?

Comment: Is your control in a Page Control?  If so, are you calling WinJS.Resources.processAll(element) during the PageControls' ready function?  I seem to be able to get this to work, though I can't tell what may be different between our two efforts.

Answer (score 1):

I'm developing Windows 8 apps in C# & XAML, so don't know what exact solution is but I think this reply might work :

I suggest, rather than creating inner classes and defining methods just in the parameters, every methods and class should be separated and combining in one method with the appropriate name given to that brand new Custom WinJS Control.
After giving name of that control you should call that through it's name in the DIV tag.

I'm not much powerfull and practiced with it's code, it's better not to serve code, sorry for it. but I'm sure, by giving name and calling through that name will help
All the Best...

**(Pardon if you think of this as not giving your answer. but i think this might help)**